# Vue method will not recognize d3 scale as a function

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I am working on a data dashboard using Vue.js and d3.js. The data is being fed from an API. The API data is stored in the "allStates" prop. This data is distributed to all the component's methods (pasted below).

Three out of the four methods are functioning/rendering properly. The fourth, drawDots, will not recognize this.xScale and this.yScale as a function. The error I continually get is "TypeError: xScale is not a function." The same error occurs with yScale.

I have moved xScale and yScale into different parts of the life cycle including computed. No luck.

I have tried to redefine them within the drawDots method. Again, no luck.

Finally, I moved all my methods in watched to ensure that only after allStates has received the data pushed to it from the promise, will the functions be called. Again, no luck.

How can I get drawDots to properly use xScale and yScale?

The full component is below.

```
<template>
  <div class="plot-chart-wrapper">
    <svg />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
export default {
  props: ["allStates"],
  data() {
    return {
      width: 1000,
      height: 300,
      margin: { top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 12 },
      xScale: "",
      yScale: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createYScale() {
      this.yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .range([0, this.height])
        .domain([80, 0]);
    },
    createXScale() {
      this.xScale = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .range([0, this.width])
        .domain(this.allStates[0].map(d => d[0]))
        .padding(0.5);
    },
    drawPlotChart() {
      d3.select(".plot-chart-wrapper svg")
        .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left)
        .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.bottom + this.margin.top);

      //x-axis
      d3.select(".plot-chart-wrapper svg")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale).tickSize([0]))
        .attr(
          "transform",
          `translate(${this.margin.left},${this.height +
            this.margin.bottom -
            20})`
        );
      d3.select(".x-axis .domain").style("visibility", "hidden");
      d3.selectAll(".x-axis .tick text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
        .filter((d, i) => i === 7)
        .text("D.C.");

      //y-axis
      d3.select(".plot-chart-wrapper svg")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .call(
          d3
            .axisRight(this.yScale)
            .tickSize([0])
            .ticks(8)
        )
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${this.margin.bottom - 20})`);
      d3.select(".y-axis .domain").style("visibility", "hidden");
    },

    drawDots() {
      d3.select(".plot-chart-wrapper svg")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "dots")
        .attr(
          "transform",
          `translate(${this.margin.left},${this.margin.bottom - 20})`
        )
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(this.allStates[0])
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .each(function(d) {
          const xScale = this.xScale;
          d3.select(this).attr("cx", xScale(d[4]));
        })
        .each(function(d) {
          const yScale = this.yScale;
          d3.select(this).attr("cy", yScale(d[0]));
        });
    }
  },
  watch: {
    allStates() {
      this.createYScale();
      this.createXScale();
      this.drawPlotChart();
      this.drawDots();
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.plot-chart-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.378);
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 5% auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the wrong `this` value inside the `each` callback function.

If you capture the component `this` in another identifier from outside the function then you can use that identifier inside the function.

```js
drawDots() {
  const vm = this

  d3.select(".plot-chart-wrapper svg")
    // ... other code
    .each(function(d) {
      const xScale = vm.xScale;
      d3.select(this).attr("cx", xScale(d[4]));
    })
```

Usually you'd use an arrow function to solve this kind of problem but I'm assuming you need the other `this` (used in `d3.select(this)`) to be the `this` value provided by `each`.

Comment: Ok I did some reading up on this. Let me make sure I have this right: When needing to reference a Vue instance within a function inside another Vue instance, you need to reassign this to vm. Does that sound correct?.

Comment: @rguttersohn Vue isn't really a factor here, it's core JavaScript and how it handles `this`. The `this` value changes whenever you enter a different function. In the outer function of your example (the function called `drawDots`) the `this` value refers to the current Vue instance. Inside the `each` handler function the `this` value is set by `d3` to some other value. So to access the outer `this` we store it in `vm`. This is only necessary because we needed access to both `this` values. If we'd only needed the outer value we could have used an arrow function, which preserves the outer `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `each`, we can also use the `attr` calls on the selection directly, keeping a reference to the scales in the function:

```
drawDots() {
  const {xScale, yScale} = this

  d3.select(".plot-chart-wrapper svg")
    // ...
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d[4])
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d[0])
```